# Vuforia Cloud Reco Image Target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

This may be a dumb question but what the hell. So I understand Vuforia Reco targets auto find the target based on your targets defined via dev portal.

How do you define which cloud reco target is assigned to a given ImageTarget?  Mainly just for reference on scale and position!!  Thanks Guys!!

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to put multiple ImageTarget prefabs in the scene. and, you won't have any option to select a target from the inspector as you get in ImageTarget component.

Normal ImageTargets: Multiple imageTarget prefabs in the scene.
Cloud-reco: One cloud-reco gameobject in the scene.

While the ImageTarget component returns whether it has been scanned or not, the cloud reco gameobject will return the name of target if its available on vuforia cloud.